# email not returned in facebook user access token validation

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

the front end of my application is doing facebook login.  it gets the auth token back and submits it to the server.  the server then calls the graph url with the token but all the server gets back is the name and id.  i'm manully calling the curl like shown:

curl -v https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=...

but the response i get is just name and id.

{"name":"Henry Robers","id":"10155954328696972"}

my application needs an email in order to create an account and send welcome letter and such so i'm stuck.  any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Er... did you just post your private access token?

Comment: Email is entirely up to the user, and optional in the latest iteration of facebook connect. If you must have it, then you will run into troubles when users elect NOT to share their email.

Comment: @AlexHowansky He did. I just invalidated it via the API.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ok cool, thanks for your vigilance. I'm not familiar with the API so wasn't sure how secret that bit was supposed to be.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Very secret, although thankfully this one had very minimal permissions. :-)

Comment: @ceejayoz <wondering how you're able to deactivate somebody else's API key>

Comment: i was under the impression my front end developer was using a test account so didn't think it was a security issue.  now i see he was using his own account

Comment: @AlexHowansky A `DELETE` request to `me/permissions` with a valid access token invalidates that token. You can do it at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ quickly.

Comment: @ceejayoz I meant, how did you have *permission* to do that? Took me a few minutes to realize, oh duh, YOU HAVE THE TOKEN, heh. I need a nap. :)

Comment: _“my application needs an email”_ - then be aware that you simply won’t get one from many users ... if they signed up to Facebook using their mobile, they might not have any email address set in their profile.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your application must have requested, and the user must have approved, the `user_email` permission. (Since you posted an active access token, I checked and you do appear to have done that.)
2. The API responds with a very small subset of fields by default. Adding `fields=foo,bar` to your call, like so, `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token=...` should get that info (assuming you did #1).
3. Don't share access tokens publicly, like you did here. I have invalidated it for you, but in many cases these will allow private data to be accessed, as well as posting on the user's behalf. Treat them as critical, private info like passwords.

Comment: i have tried your example but i still only get name and id:     curl -v https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token=<TOKEN>         {"name":"Henry Robers","id":"<id>"}

Comment: @radamnyc When you publicly shared the access token, I tested it and was able to get the email address. However, since I invalidated that token and its permissions, you may need to re-request the `user_email` permission now.

Comment: thanks for your help, is that something that EACH user must say yes to or is that something that we set up for our application?

Comment: @radamnyc Each user must be asked for and accept the permission via the OAuth flow. Some will reject it, and remember also that some Facebook users **don't have an email address** - Facebook permits phone-number-only signups as well. As such, your application will need to detect this and prompt the user to reapprove the permission or ask for their email in those cases.

Comment: ok, so we need to figure out someway around if someone authenticates with facebook but doesn't allow us to get the email

Comment: Correct. You can check `me/permissions` for the `user_email` permission to see if they granted it.